# Are there noticeable jumps in index options price due to systematic hedging of structured products close to big expiry dates?

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, derivatives

I am looking at investigating factors that will cause jumps in index options prices close to big expiries in the name. I imagine systematic rebalancing of structured products will have a large impact but I'd be interested in hearing if there are other factors that would cause this kind of behaviour.

Comment: How do you propose to determine if there is an usual amount of structured products expiring at a certain date? I.e. what is a "big expiration"?

Comment: Apologies I meant around expiration dates of the index options not the structured products